# Segmentation fault error in importing sentence_transformers in Azure Machine Learning Service Nvidia Compute

Tags: azure, nvidia, azure-machine-learning-service, roberta-language-model, sentence-transformers

I would like to use sentence_transformers in AML to run XLM-Roberta model for sentence embedding. I have a script in which I import sentence_transformers:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
```

Once I run my AML pipeline, the run fails on this script with the following error:

```
AzureMLCompute job failed.
UserProcessKilledBySystemSignal: Job failed since the user script received system termination signal usually due to out-of-memory or segfault.
    Cause: segmentation fault
    TaskIndex: 
    NodeIp: #####
    NodeId: #####
```

I'm pretty sure that this import is causing this error, because if I comment out this import, the rest of the script will run.
This is weird because the installation of the sentence_transformers succeed.

This is the details of my compute:

```
Virtual machine size
STANDARD_NV24 (24 Cores, 224 GB RAM, 1440 GB Disk)
Processing Unit
GPU - 4 x NVIDIA Tesla M60
```

Agent Pool:

```
Azure Pipelines
```

Agent Specification:

```
ubuntu-16.04
```

requirements.txt file:

```
torch==1.4.0
sentence-transformers
```

Does anyone have a solution for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the pytorch version from 1.4.0 to 1.6.0.
So the requirements.txt looks like this:

```
torch==1.6.0
sentence-transformers
```

At first I tried one of the older versions of sentence-transformers which was compatible with pytorch 1.4.0. But the older version doesn't support "xml-roberta-base" model, so I tried to upgrade the pytorch version.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue when trying to install sentence-transformers 2.2.2 in a Python 10 environment. The installation process failed with an error message. After some troubleshooting, I found a solution that worked for me.
I downgraded my Python installation from version 10 to version 8, and then I was able to install sentence-transformers 2.2.2 without any issues. It seems that there is some incompatibility between sentence-transformers and Python 10.
If you're facing a similar issue, I suggest trying this solution. Of course, downgrading your Python installation may not be ideal if you're using other packages that require Python 10.

Comment: This could be the issue, unless I'm getting this error with `Python 3.9.x` as well https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/1319